# Morse Code Decoder on Processing Adaptation Problem

Tags: java, arduino, processing, decoder, morse-code

I'm trying to do Morse Code Decoder on Processing. I'm having Arduino codes for it, but I want to do it without any physical instrument or another button, only using my computer and a mouse click.

Here is the [link](https://www.instructables.com/id/Morse-Code-Decoder/) for that I used for Arduino.

I'm trying to optimize the Arduino code that I found on the internet, to the Processing but not having any expertise on Processing.

```
/*
  PROGRAM TO DECIPHER MORSE CODE USING A PUSH BUTTON AND DISPLAY IT ON THE SERIAL MONITOR
  DATE: 20 JANUARY 2017
  AUTHORS: PINAKI SADHUKHAN AND PRIYANKA SADHUKHAN
*/

unsigned long signal_len,t1,t2;   //time for which button is pressed
int inputPin = 2;                 //input pin for push button
int ledPin = 4;                   //outpu pin for LED
String code = "";                 //string in which one alphabet is stored

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT_PULLUP); //internal pullup resistor is used to simplify the circuit
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
NextDotDash:
  while (digitalRead(inputPin) == HIGH) {}
  t1 = millis();                            //time at button press
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);               //LED on while button pressed
  while (digitalRead(inputPin) == LOW) {}
  t2 = millis();                            //time at button release
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);                //LED off on button release
  signal_len = t2 - t1;                     //time for which button is pressed
  if (signal_len > 50)                      //to account for switch debouncing
  {
    code += readio();                       //function to read dot or dash
  }
  while ((millis() - t2) < 500)           //if time between button press greater than 0.5sec, skip loop and go to next alphabet
  {     
    if (digitalRead(inputPin) == LOW)
    {
      goto NextDotDash;
    }
  }
  convertor();                          //function to decipher code into alphabet
}

char readio()
{
  if (signal_len < 600 && signal_len > 50)
  {
    return '.';                        //if button press less than 0.6sec, it is a dot
  }
  else if (signal_len > 600)
  {
    return '-';                        //if button press more than 0.6sec, it is a dash
  }
}

void convertor()
{
  static String letters[] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-",
                             ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "E"
                            };
  int i = 0;
  if (code == ".-.-.-")
  {
    Serial.print(".");        //for break
  }
  else
  {
    while (letters[i] != "E")  //loop for comparing input code with letters array
    {
      if (letters[i] == code)
      {
        Serial.print(char('A' + i));
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }
    if (letters[i] == "E")
    {
      Serial.println("<Wrong input>");  //if input code doesn't match any letter, error
    }
  }
  code = "";                            //reset code to blank string
}
```

I'm trying to adapt it to Processing3 but, many of the codes do not have compatibility with Processing, instead of both of them using Java language. All of my struggles are in vain.

Comment: Hello! What exactly is your question? You may want to read [How to ask a good quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. You'll find that this community is very helpful... as long as you respect it's conventions!

Comment: why is this tagged java?

Comment: @Piglet Arduino IDE is Java based program, isn't it?

Comment: I don't see how the languange the IDE was written in is relevant for your post. The code you have here is C++. Or better some Arduino specific dialect of it. I'm not sure what kind of help you expect here. Just do some tutorials...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% what you want to know but I guess you want to implement a morse decoder in Processing and all you have is an Arduino implementation.

So rather than trying to translate an Arduino implementation (which is not a bad idea if you can read Arduino code) why not simply implement it from scratch.

Here's what you need to know, if you want to use your mouse:

- How to process mouse button press and release
- How to measure time
- The timings of the specific morse code you want to decode
- How to output some text
- Some basic Processing knowledge so you can use variables and control structures

This knowledge can quickly be obtained through websearch.

Then you measure how long the mouse is pressed down each time it is pressed down.
This gives you . and _ which you then combine to characters which give you words.